# How to set up anonymous login with XMPPFramework - iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I'm trying to set up an anonymous login so my users don't have to create an account an account on the eJabberd server to use the chat room. The configuration for the server in the ejabberd.cfg is:

```
{host_config, "bubble", [{auth_method, anonymous},
                         {anonymous_protocol, login_anon}]}.
```

My method to connect the client to the XMPPStream:

```
- (BOOL)connect {
    [self setupStream];

    if (![self.xmppStream isDisconnected]) {
        return YES;
    }

    if (![PFUser currentUser]) {
        return NO;
    }

    NSString *currentUserId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@bubble",[PFUser currentUser].objectId];

    [self.xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:currentUserId]];
    self.xmppStream.hostName = kJABBER_HOSTNAME;

    NSError *error = nil;


    if (![self.xmppStream connectWithTimeout:10 error:&error]) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't connect to server %@", [error localizedDescription]]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];


        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

As well as the xmppStreamDidConnect method:

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender {
    self.isOpen = YES;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if(![self.xmppStream authenticateAnonymously:&error]) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't connect to server %@", [error localizedDescription]]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

When I try to login into the server, it keep on getting "The server does no support anonymous authentication".

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I am currently facing the same issue!

Comment: @funkenstrahlen I figured it out quite some time ago and ended up writing a blog post on it https://medium.com/@dylanshine/building-a-group-chat-with-the-xmppframework-59fa17ecf4a0#.z3ma8yedj.

Answer (score 0):

From the XMPPFramework documentation:

*If you wish to use anonymous authentication, you should still set myJID prior to calling connect. You can simply set it to something like **"anonymous@domain"**, where "domain" is the proper domain. After the authentication process, you can query the myJID property to see what your assigned JID is.*

Make sure that the settings on the server allow anonymous login as well.

If you don't have access to the serve configuration you can still check if the server allows anonymous login using something like:

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream*)sender
{
    self.isXmppConnected = YES;

    if ([self.xmppStream supportsAnonymousAuthentication]) {
        NSError* error = nil;
        //the server does support anonymous auth
        [self.xmppStream authenticateAnonymously:&error];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"The server does not support anonymous authentication");
    }
}
```

Be sure to place it in the didConnect delegate method, as it needs to be connected first.